# Alert the dropping order - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

i have tree list( one parent and 4 children), if i change the children position alert box will display the order.

for example

i have children 1, 2, 3, 4 and if i drag the 4 child and place it in the 2 position

alert will display the order like  1, 4, 2, 3.

[image: you cac see it as image]

and jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/AXDQL/.

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking.   Could you write a sentence which starts with "how" and ends with a question mark?  
I would suggest you do that even if Nicola have miraculously managed to read your mind (I have no idea if his answer is addressing what you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
** mind reading mode on (please write question that are understandable withouth links **
```

You can do (you must use the stop function otherwise the alert is fired twice):

```
 $( ".droptrue" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.mt",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var order = ui.item.prevAll().length;
        alert(order);
        //$.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
        //$("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
     //});                                                              
    }                                      
 });
```

fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/AXDQL/2/

EDIT - to do what you want you could do this:

```
var addPositions = function() {
    $('.droptrue').each(function() {
        var position = 1;
        $(this).children().each(function() {

            $(this).data('position', position);
            position++;
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var treeList = "";
    treeList = "<ul id=\"createTree\" class=\"droptrue1\">";
    for (var key in jsonObj) {
        //alert("key: " + key + ", value: " + jsonObj[key])
        for (var skey in jsonObj[key]) {
            treeList += ("<li class=\"listTree\" id=\"asdf\">" + skey + "<ul class=\"droptrue mt\">");
            for (var sskey in jsonObj[key][skey]) {
                for (var ssskey in jsonObj[key][skey][sskey]) {
                    treeList += ("<li class=\"innerList\">" + jsonObj[key][skey][sskey][ssskey] + "</li>");
                }
            }
            treeList += "</ul></li>";
        }
    }
    treeList += "</ul>";
    $('#tree').append(treeList);
    addPositions();



    $(".droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul.mt",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var order = [];
            ui.item.closest('ul').children('li').each(function() {
                order.push($(this).data('position'));
                });
            alert(order.join(', '));
                //$.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
            //$("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            //});                                                              
            }
        });
    $("ul.droptrue1").sortable();
    });
```

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/AXDQL/6